# Unitary matricies $U$ with $U\gamma^0 U^* = \gamma^0$

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I'm interessted in the set of all matrices $U \in Mat_{4,4}(\mathbb{C})$ with the property $U\gamma^0U^* = \gamma^0$ where $\gamma^0 = diag(1,1,-1,-1)$.

I guess that the matrices should be unitary and I know that all matrices of $U(2,2) \subset U(4)$ satisfy this condition. But I'm not sure if there are matrices beyond $U(2,2)$ with this property?

Answer (score 1):

$U$ doesn't have to be unitary. You may take
$$
U=\pmatrix{V_1\\ &V_2}\pmatrix{(1+|D|^2)^{1/2}&D^\ast\\ D&(1+|D|^2)^{1/2}}\pmatrix{V_3\\ &V_4}
$$
where $D\in M_2(\mathbb C)$ is any diagonal matrix and $V_1,V_2,V_3,V_4$ are arbitrary $2\times2$ unitary matrices. $U$ is not unitary when $D\ne0$.